# MarkLogic basic questions on equivalent of SELECT with Java API

Tags: java, sql, json, nosql, marklogic

I'm new to NoSQL and slugging through the documentation.

I have a MarkLogic DB instance populated with JSON documents that interest me.  I have executed a basic search and have a SearchHandle that will give me the URIs that matched.

Great.

Well I want to evaluate the values for some specific keys in those JSON documents

In SQL this is a simple SELECT  from  where  ='somevalue'.

Here, I'm struggling to find the proper way to actually accomplish this.  I set up my JSONDocumentManager, establish my search term criteria to get my documents, and I get back a result to my StringHandle.

Am I required to now parse through the flattened JSON string looking for my key?

Do I need to convert the entire JSON document into a POJO through a JacksonHandle binding just to lookup a single value in a document by URI?

I can't help but think this is probably a one-liner I haven't spotted in the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Raevik:

Like SQL SELECT (which is designed for result sets and returns a single value only for a query filtering to one row and projecting one column), MarkLogic query responses are designed to return multiple documents, structures, or values from very large data sets. As in SQL, a single value is the special case of a query that qualifies one document and extracts one value.

The simplest approach for defining that query is probably to use extraction with Query By Example. Please see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe#id_54044

You can also define a range index on the JSON key in the documents using the Admin UI:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_95526

and then use the QueryManager.values() method to extract one value from the range index.

MarkLogic 7 does support SPARQL, which has syntax to get a single answer, so by persisting your data as triples, those queries would be possible.

For completeness: you can also filter on a JSON key either by using StructuredQueryBuilder and specifying a value query with a JSON key as in (untested):

```
StructuredQuery queryDef = queryBldr.value(queryBldr.jsonKey("key"),"value");
```

or by using Query by Example as in (untested):

```
StructuredQuery queryDef = newRawQueryByExampleDefinition(new StringHandle("{\"$query\":{\"key\":\"value\"}}"));
```

For more detail about these filtering capabilities, please see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe

By the way, Jackson should be usable not only for databinding to POJOs but also ad hoc DOM access to JSON.

Hoping that helps.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken (which is entirely possible), but these suggestions don't produce a value but instead produce whole documents, yes?  My issue is with figuring out the best way to manage the returned document for something as simple as getting a value from the result-set, not establishing a criteria for the query.  Am I making any sense?

Comment: I expanded the part of the answer about projection -- hoping that gets you closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic supports `xquery` which is [sortof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLWOR) a cousin to `SQL`:

```
   for $d in doc("depts.xml")//deptno
   let $e := doc("emps.xml")//employee[deptno = $d]
   where count($e) >= 10
   order by avg($e/salary) descending
   return
     <big-dept>
        { $d,
           <headcount>{count($e)}</headcount>,
           <avgsal>{avg($e/salary)}</avgsal>
        }
     </big-dept>
```